# Checking if given sum is attainable with any combination of nodes in a BST Python

Tags: python-2.7, recursion, sum, binary-search-tree

I'm working on an assignment for a university Python class, given this code to create a binary search tree,

```
# creates an empty tree
def createEmptyTree():
     return None

# adds a value to a BST and returns a pointer to the modified BST
def add(tree, value):
    if tree == None:
        return {'data':value, 'left':None, 'right':None}
    elif value < tree['data']:
        tree['left'] = add(tree['left'],value)
        return tree
    elif value > tree['data']:
        tree['right'] = add(tree['right'],value)
        return tree

def main():
    myTree = createEmptyTree()  
    myTree = add(myTree, 20)
    myTree = add(myTree, 2)
    myTree = add(myTree, 25)
    myTree = add(myTree, 14)
    myTree = add(myTree, 75)
    myTree = add(myTree, 93)
    print hasSum(myTree, 22)
```

In one function, hasSum(tree, Sum) I'm asked to check(True/False) if a given integer is attainable with any sum combination of the nodes in the BST.

Here is my code so far,

```
def hasSum(tree, Sum):
    if tree == None :
        return False
    else :
        leftSum = hasSum(tree['left'], Sum)
        rightSum = hasSum(tree['right'], Sum)
        if leftSum == Sum or rightSum == Sum :
            return True
```

But it's returning None, please tell me what I'm doing wrong, I'm still working on mastering recursion.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this one matches true for 20,22,36,45,120,213

```
def hasSum(tree, Sum):

    if tree is not None:

        Decrement = tree['data']
        Sum = Sum - Decrement

        if Sum == 0:
            return True

        else:
            return hasSum(tree['right'], Sum) or hasSum(tree['left'], Sum)

i = 0
while (i<300):
    i+=1
    if hasSum(myTree,i):
        print i, hasSum(myTree,i)
```

Comment: are we allowed to have more parameters in the method e.g. could i do hasSum(tree, sum, level)? Just want to know what restraints there are with this question?

Comment: was this of any use at all?

Answer (score 0):

Do an in-order traversal.

For each node, compute the difference ("k - currentnode's value", where K is final sum).

Keep track of node values you've seen so far, in a 'set'.

If the target is in the set, return True.

Else, add currentnode's value to the set.

```
def checkSum(root, k, seen = set()):
    if root:
        checkSum(root.left, k, seen)
        target = k-root.value
        #print "Seen", seen
        #print "Value", root.value
        #print "Target", target
        if target in seen:
            return True
        else:
            seen.add(root.value)
        checkSum(root.right, k, seen)
    return False
```